# Odoo 10 Error when generating a xlsx report

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, xlsxwriter

I would like export custom report in `xlsx`. i try below code but when i press button export, it error `AccessDenied: Access denied`.

```
odoo.addons.web.controllers.main: An exception occured during an http request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 72, in wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1480, in index
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 118, in dispatch_rpc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\report.py", line 32, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\security.py", line 13, in check
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\base\res\res_users.py", line 507, in check
AccessDenied: Access denied
```

**Report XML:**

```
<report 
    id="action_report_excel"
    model="account.invoice"
    string="Export to XLSX"
    report_type="xlsx"
    name="module_name.report_name.xlsx"
    file="module_name.report_name.xlsx"
    attachment_use="False"
/>
```

**Python Code:**

```
from report_xlsx.report.report_xlsx import ReportXlsx

class CustomReportXlsx(ReportXlsx):

    def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, objs):
        for obj in objs:
            report_name = obj.name
            # One sheet by partner
            sheet = workbook.add_worksheet(report_name[:31])
            bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
            sheet.write(0, 0, obj.name, bold)

CustomReportXlsx('report.module_name.report_name.xlsx', 'account.invoice')
```

**Python Wizard:**

```
def check_report(self):
    data = {}
    return self.env['report'].sudo().get_action(self, 'module_name.report_name.xlsx', data=data)
```

help me, please

Comment: You superuser_id when calling report from py. That may be help you out here.

Comment: assign user rights.

Comment: @KevalMehta Do you mean use superuser_id in return action report on wizard? `Ex. return self.env['report'].sudo(superuser_id).get_action right?`

Comment: @BhoomiPatel  i try already create ACL but same error. How to assign user rights.

Answer (score 1):

Add proper access rights for model **account.invoice**. your current user has no access power to read/write data from **account.invoice** model

Comment: Do you mean that I create an ACL file for the account.invoice model?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in my odoov10 community after playing with some package configurations related with xlsx and other things. [image]

Note that, if this issue is related to a single customized xlsx report, definitely it is related to access levels(Unfortunately, i faced this for all my xls). I can draw my issues and findings as points like below:

- I couldn't print ANY XLSX file from odoo
- Getting error box "**AccessDenied: Access denied**" from odoo for "ALL" my excel reports.
- Error is raising from "**odoo\addons\base\res\res_users.py**" line number 503 (May little vary based on your odoo clone.) and the function is named  "**def check(cls, db, uid, passwd):**"
- When I check some work arrounds, I got that the argument "**passwd**" is getting "False" , which leads to this access denied error.

**Milky Solution:**

Since this issue was in my localhost, and the time was limited, I just passed my admin password into that function manually (Even it is not goof at all).

- My Code of "odoo\addons\base\res\res_users.py" just altered like below:
- `passwd = '<MY_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD' if not passwd: # empty passwords disallowed for obvious security reasons raise AccessDenied()`

where the function failed with this hard code, I fixed this issue.